# Linq group by DateTime.Date and then group by another criterium

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have an `IEnumerable<Bar>`, where Bar contains among other data a `DateTime` type variable `TimeStamp`.

I have the following code,

```
var convertedBars = from myData in bars
                    group myData by (int) myData.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes / 60 into barData
                    select new Bar(){
                        TimeStamp = barData.FirstOrDefault().TimeStamp,
                        Open = barData.FirstOrDefault().Open,
                        Low = barData.Min(bd => bd.Low),
                        High = barData.Max(bd => bd.High),
                        Close = barData.LastOrDefault().Close,
                    };
```

which returns an `IEnumerable<Bar>` where bars are grouped into 60 minute bars. This works fine as long as the original `bars` collection contains bars of only one and the same day timestamp. If the source collection contains multiple days then all bars are grouped into a maximum of 24 hourly buckets.

How can I adjust the code so that the collection is first grouped by `Date` and then grouped by `TotalMinutes /60` (such as above) in order to end up with 60 minute buckets separately for each date?

**EDIT**

I generalized the query somewhat, could someone comment whether that is the correct approach or am I missing something obvious?

```
var requestedTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1); //1 hour
long numberTicks = requestedTimeSpan.Ticks;
var convertedBars = from myData in bars
                    group myData by myData.TimeStamp.Ticks / numberTicks  into barData
                    select new Bar()
                    {
                        TimeStamp = new DateTime(barData.Key * numberTicks),
                        Open = barData.First().Open,
                        Low = barData.Min(bd => bd.Low),
                        High = barData.Max(bd => bd.High),
                        Close = barData.Last().Close,
                    };
```

Comment: you can try `group myData by new{ Date=myData.Date, minutes = (int) myData.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes / 60} into barData`

Comment: Use `Key` in stead of `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @GertArnold, well but that would imply an additional operation as the key only contains the Date portion and a useless group classifier

Comment: OK, in this case all TimeStamps (and Open?) in a group are identical but in general you never know what the first item in a group will be without sorting. Sometimes people just are not aware of the `Key` property yet.

Comment: @GertArnold, ok I see your point, I adjusted to `TimeStamp = barData.Key.Date.AddMinutes(barData.Key.minute * 60)`. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @MattWolf i think Tim already add answer :-) just add name for calculated member

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, using an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) for the grouping:

```
group myData by new { myData.TimeStamp.Date,
       Hour = (int) myData.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes / 60 } into barData
```

Comment: thanks, though I think you need to assign a simple name or member access expression to the minute portion such as @Grundy did

Comment: @MattWolf Ah, you're right. I've added a name of `Hour`. The first field is named `Date` automatically (inferred from the property name).

Comment: Tim, do you mind taking a quick look at my edit? I generalized things somewhat and operate just on ticks. My hunch (though I have not profiled it yet) is that the query will be faster because the grouping on long values should most likely be faster than on DateTime structs. But I wonder whether it is the right way to go about it. I am asking because it looks a little too obvious shortcut to me, but have not seen this approach anywhere else.

Comment: @MattWolf I think that your edit is good, and that it will work correctly. Only thing: your `Open` and `Close` calculations will only work if `bars` is already ordered by time. If this is not already guaranteed, you should order them correctly in order to find the right values.

Comment: thanks for taking a peek, yes the `bars` is an ordered collection, thanks for point this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var convertedBars =
        bars.GroupBy(b => b.TimeStamp.Date).Select(g => g.GroupBy(b2 => (int)(b2.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes / 60))).Select(gb => new Bar()
        {                
            TimeStamp = gb.FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault().TimeStamp,
            Open = gb.FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault().Open,
            Low = gb.SelectMany(bd => bd).Min(ibd => ibd.Low),
            High = gb.SelectMany(bd => bd).Max(ibd => ibd.High),
            Close = gb.LastOrDefault().LastOrDefault().Close,
        });
```